# Why in-order traversal of a threaded tree is O(N)?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I can't seem to figure out how the in-order traversal of a threaded binary tree is O(N)..
Because you have to descend the links to find the the leftmost child and then go back by the thread when you want to add the parent to the traversal path. would not that be O(N^2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traversal of a tree (threaded or not) is O(N) because visiting any node, starting from its parent, is O(1). The visitation of a node consists of three fixed operations: descending to the node from parent, the visitation proper (spending time at the node), and then returning to the parent.  O(1 * N) is O(N).

The ultimate way to look at it is that the tree is a graph, and the traversal crosses each edge in the graph only twice. And the number of edges is proportional to the number of nodes since there are no cycles or redundant edges (each node can be reached by one unique path). A tree with N nodes has exactly N-1 edges: each node has an edge leading to it from its parent node, except for the root node of the tree.

At times it appears as if visiting a node requires more than one descent. For instance, after visiting the rightmost node in a subtree, we have to pop back up numerous levels before we can march to the right into the next subtree.  But we did not descend all the way down just to visit **that** node.  Each one-level descent can be accounted for as being necessary for visiting just the node immediately below, and the opposite ascent's 
cost is lumped with that.  By visiting a node V, we also gain access to all the nodes below it, but all those nodes benefit from and share the edge traversal from V's parent down to V, and back up again.

This is related to amortized analysis, which applies in situations where we can globally understand the overall cost based on some general observation about the structure of the problem, but at the detailed level of the individual operations, the costs are distributed in an uneven way that appears confusing.

Amortized analysis helps us understand that, for instance, N insertions into a hash table which resizes itself by growing exponentially are O(N).  Most of the insertion operations are quick, but from time to time, we grow the table and process its contents.  This is similar to how, from time to time during a tree traversal, we have to perform numerous consecutive ascents to climb out of a deep subtree.

The global observation about the hash table is that each item inserted into the table will move to a larger table on average about three times in three resize operations, and so each insertion can be regarded as "pre paying" for three re-insertions, which is a fixed cost. Of course, "older" items will be moved more times, but this is offset by "younger" entries that move fewer times, diluting the cost.  And the global observation about the tree was already noted above: it has N-1 edges, each of which are traversed exactly twice during the traversal, so the visitation of each node "pays" for the double traversal of its respective edge. Because this is so easy to see, we don't actually have to formally apply amortized analysis to tree traversal.

Now suppose we performed an individual searches for each node (and the tree is a balanced search tree).  Then the traversal would still not be O(N*N), but rather O(N log N).  Suppose we have an ordered search tree which holds consecutive integers. If we increment over the integers and perform individual searches for each value, then each search is O(log N), and we end up doing N of these. In this situation, the edge traversals are no longer shared, so amortization does not apply. To reach some given node that we are searching for which is found at depth D, we have to cross D edges twice, for the sake of that node and that node alone. The next search in the loop for another integer will be completely independent of the previous one.

It may also help you to think of a linked list, which can be regarded as a very unbalanced tree. To visit all the items in a linked list of length N and return back to the head node is obviously O(N).   Searching for each item individually is O(N*N), but in a traversal, we are not searching for each node individually, but using each predecessor as a springboard into finding the next node.

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop to find the parent. Otherwise said, you are going through each arc between two node twice. That would be 2*number of arc = 2*(number of node -1) which is O(N).